# Javascript method called by setInterval will not change src of img element

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I'm trying to update an image every 200 ms using `setInterval` and `element.setAttribute('src', 'suchandsuch.BMP')`

jsFiddle Link:
[Fiddle-dee-dee](https://jsfiddle.net/52e6p0vs/)

The initial setting of the image element's src attribute works fine but subsequent attempts to update from the `updatePic` function called by `setInterval` never update it. Other bits of code I put in there work fine. For instance the `level` object's value is incremented and `alert('wtf')` calls also work but not the setting of the attribute. I'm pulling my hair out.

```
function showMorphPic() {

  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyStroke, false);
  var picPrefixes = ['A', 'B'];
  var picLevel = {value: 0};
  var prefix = picPrefixes[Math.floor(Math.random() * picPrefixes.length)];

  morphPic.setAttribute('src', 'img/morphPics/' + prefix + picLevel.value + '.BMP');

  var picMorphTimer = setInterval(updatePic, 200, picLevel);

}

function updatePic(level) {

  if (level.value < 100) {
    level.value = level.value + 2;
    morphPic.setAttribute("src", "img/morphPics/" + prefix + level.value + ".BMP");
  } else {
    clearInterval(picMorphTimer);
  }
}
```

Comment: _"Fiddle-dee-dee"_ - browser error consoleelee ...

Comment: I don't know the actual size of the images, but 200ms is not much time for a bitmap...

Comment: I'm assuming *WTF*  stands for work time factor

Comment: `updatePic()` is trying to use variables (`prefix`, `picMorphTimer`) defined locally in the other function, so that won't work.

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean? I'm not sure why the 'Start Practice' button isn't working but in the fiddle but it works in my browser when I open it up directly.

Comment: 'Start Practice" doesn't work in the fiddle because it has an inline `onclick=` attribute that only has access to call global functions, but in the fiddle all your JS is contained inside an onload handler, so not global.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you so much! Oh my god, I'll send you $10 on paypal if you PM your email or something. Or I can reddit gold you. I don't know if this site has anything similar. Thank you!

Comment: This site doesn't deal with monetary rewards. Normally you would just "reward" people by upvoting answers that helped you, and accepting the one that helped the most. I didn't post an answer in this case because the thing I pointed out in my other comment seemed too trivial and I wasn't sure if there were other issues beyond that. Anyway, you don't have to pay me (or any other members here); if you're really overflowing with gratitude donate to the Red Cross or something.

Comment: I'll donate to Doctor's without Borders in your honor friend. Thanks again. Wasn't trying to be rude, just really grateful :)

Comment: add your this var picPrefixes = ['A', 'B'];
  var picLevel = {value: 0};
  var prefix = picPrefixes[Math.floor(Math.random() * picPrefixes.length)]; in your updatePic like said as @nnnnnn